# Xcode C++ Vectors: Implicit instantiation of undefined template

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, header, implicit

I ran this code on a different IDE and it was successful. For some reason I get the above error message on Xcode. I assume I'm missing a header of some kind, but I'm not sure which one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    vector<string> listRestaurants;  // error: Implicit instantiation of undefined template
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `std` namespace houses both of those templates. Change `vector` to `std::vector`, and `string` to `std::string`.

Comment: I wonder what broken toolchain accepts this code as-is.

Answer (score 22):

Xcode 10.2.1 was showing me the error 
`Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::string> listRestaurants;

  ....
  return 0;
}
```

Fixed my issue.

Comment: Just adding `#include <vector>` fixed my issues.

Answer (score 10):

If adding std:: is not the issue for you, then check if you have `#include <vector>`. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Didn't realize that `#include <vector>` is required. I thought it was part of standard library template; I ran this code in VSCODE IDE and it worked fine for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    uint_least8_t i; // trying to be conscious of the size of the int
    vector<int> vect;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
    {
        vect.push_back(i);
    }
    for(auto i : vect) 
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> The `std` namespace houses both of those templates. Change `vector` to `std::vector`, and `string` to `std::string`. – [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig)

Answer (score 0):

the vector and string were placed in the namespace std
using namespace std;

Comment: [**Never** use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: He didn't say to use using. You always can use like std::vector or std::string. 
By the way @RyanLi was right.